# compute Pr($X_1>X_2$)

Tags: probability

I have two iid random variables $X_1,X_2$ with cdf $F$. I want to compute Pr($X_1>X_2$) and express it with $F$.

Is it correct to use the following?
Pr($X_1>X_2$)=Pr($X_1>x|X_2=x$)=$1-F(x)$

Thank you

Comment: If they're i.i.d., then $P(X_1>X_2)=P(X_2>X_1)=\left(1-P(X_1=X_2)\right)/2$.  Unless $F$ has discontinuities, $P(X_1=X_2)$ is just $0$, and the answer is $1/2$.

Comment: "Is it correct to use the following?" No it is not, to begin with, because the LHS does not depend on $x$ while the RHS does (although one is not said what $x$ is).

Answer (score 1):

The probability of the sum of random variables $X,Y$ is given by their convolution: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf. But first, you need to compute the distribution of $-X_2$ by expressing it as the composition of $X_2$ with some function $f$.

Then, from the distribution of $X_1-X_2$, you can compute $P(X_1-X_2>0)$ .

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Potato:How so? Isn't $P(X_1>X_2)=P(X_1-X_2>0$) ? Then, knowing the distribution of $X_1-X_2$ allows us to calculate $P(X_1-X_2>0)$

Comment: Any other downvoter care to explain what's wrong?

Comment: Well, this seems to be a site where answers are determined by some authority. I may be wrong, but I made specific claims, and those claims can be refuted in their own terms. Kind of disappointing that this is not how this is being addressed.

Comment: What you have now does answer the question. What you had before did not. Just stating the that the probability of a sum of random variables is given by their convolution is unhelpful, in my opinion. However, in light of what you've added, I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @Potato: thanks for your reply; I just hoped for some feedback.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Also, be aware that one hour is not a particularly long amount of time for this site. People will probably reply to your comments, but it might take them a few hours. Especially if they live in a radically different time zone and are asleep when you post.